# Best practice: Using redundant methods from external libraries

Tags: c#, dry

In the code base I'm working on there are several examples of

```
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
}
```

According to the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) this is redundant because createDirectory won't overwrite an existing directory.

This could be seen as making the code clearer, as it's not obvious from the `.CreateDirectory(dir)` method that this is the behaviour.

On the flip side, this is code bloat and keeping it around (even adding it to a library/utility class) has its issues (means you have to read/maintain more lines of code for example).

What's considered best practice here?

Comment: `createDirectory won't overwrite and existing directory`, While this is true, wont it still throw an exception if the directory *does* exist?  I'm not at a position to test this right now, but I would think that the `if` is to prevent an `IOException` at this block.

Comment: @EvanL Nope - it just returns the info for it with no issues

Comment: Without the `Directory.Exists` the code would cause me to pause and review it. Even if that wasn't what I was dealing with at the time. I'd prefer the check to help developers reading the code think `nothing to see here, move along`.

Comment: I stand corrected, knew I shouldn't open my big mouth without actually trying first ;)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Isn't that what a comment is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may look redundant, but I can see a reason why someone decided to go that way.

The main difference is:

- `Directory.Exists()` returns just `bool`
- `Directory.CreateDirectory()` returns `DirectoryInfo`

So even when the directory exists, there is additional work performed to get that `DirectoryInfo` instance, which may not be necessary at all.

Another thing that come up is the fact, that you have to know that `Directory.CreateDirectory` does not override the directory if it exists! With additional `Directory.Exists` call even when someone doesn't know that he can really easily figure out what's going on with this piece of code.

And I don't think there is a `best practice` here.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would normally remove the redundant code.

> This could be seen as making the code clearer, as it's not obvious from the .CreateDirectory(dir) method that this is the behaviour.

In general, I'd argue that would be better served by a comment, rather than a redundant code path.  Adding extra code to avoid a lack of knowledge seems like a weak reason to include the check.

That being said, there is a potential (very minor) performance gain in avoiding the call to `CreateDirectory`, as that method will construct a `DirectoryInfo` instance.  In practice, this is most likely "noise" (as IO calls tend to be relatively expensive anyways), so its not something I would factor into the equation unless it proved to be a measured problem.

Comment: I'd agree wholeheartedly that commenting code that could appear strange (Why didn't the previous programmer check if the directory existed first?) to someone without the full understanding of a methods internal workings is always a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

A race condition could cause the creation of a directory to fail even if the preliminary check has passed.
Therefore I consider this code as incorrect and I dissuade you from using it.

Comment: I'd agree - except that, in this case, it's likely the same race condition will occur as soon as you try to *use* the directory - in which case, the real problem will happen on file write (like it should).

Comment: How does `Directory.CreateDirectory()` prevent race conditions? Internally it still does an exists check before creating.

Comment: @DaveShaw: .NET "CreateDirectory" internally calls the native Win32 function "CreateDirectory" that returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS if the specified directory already exists.

Comment: Yes, but it does an "if exists" check before calling that, so the same race condition you described can occur by just calling `CreateDirecory()`.